# Insert data into multiple tables from single form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the form as mentioned below.

and getting the following output.

Help me to get the output as following with foreach loop.

```
array('notification') = array('pos_id' => 'kiran','post_usr' => 'kumar','comment' => 'kaleti');
array('project') = array('Project_name' => 'india','Proejct_lang' => 'hyderabad');
```

Here is controller code.

```
// controller
public function form_submit() { 
  $total_data = $this->input->post(); 
  print_r($total_data);
  //output :Array ( [notification|pos_id] => kiran [notification|post_usr] => kumar [notification|comment] => kaleti [project|Project_name] => india [project|Proejct_lang] => hyderabad )
  foreach ( $total_data as $key => $value ) { 
    $arr = explode("|",$key); 
    echo $arr[0]."--".$arr[1]."--".$value."<br />"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: according to the array, you can insert your data in a table, where is the issue now?

Comment: what code you had write till now.

Comment: @M.Hemant Sir, Please check below code in controller.public function form_submit()
  {
  $total_data = $this->input->post();
  foreach ( $total_data as $key => $value )
  {
   $arr = explode("|",$key);
   echo $arr[0]."--".$arr[1]."--".$value."<br />";  
   
  }
  }

Comment: @NomanJaved Sir, how to convert the mentioned output to array format. see my controller function here ::: public function form_submit()
  {
  $total_data = $this->input->post();
  foreach ( $total_data as $key => $value )
  {
   $arr = explode("|",$key);
   echo $arr[0]."--".$arr[1]."--".$value."<br />";  
   
  }
  }

Comment: first check the value. add `echo"<pre>";print_r($value);exit;` in foreach loop and check the data returned.

Comment: @NomanJaved sir, please check the output before foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is controller code you will get data from `VIEW` as input fields of view that you will collect in `controller`.

```
// Controller
$data_array1 = array(
    'table_field_name_here' => $this->input->post('pos_id'),
    'table_field_name_here' => $this->input->post('post_usr'),
    'table_field_name_here' => $this->input->post('comment'),
);

$data_array2 = array(
    'table_field_name_here' => $this->input->post('Project_name'),
    'table_field_name_here' => $this->input->post('Proejct_lang'),
);  

$table_1 = 'table_name';
$table_2 = 'table_name';
$record_id_1 = $this->Common_model->insert_into_table($table_1, $data_array1);
$record_id_2 = $this->Common_model->insert_into_table($table_2, $data_array2);
if($record_id_1 && $record_id_2){
    // success ...!
}else{
    // fail ...!    
}
```

The `model` function which you will call from your controller.

```
// Model
function insert_into_table($table, $data) {
    // echo "<pre>asdf";print_r($data);exit;
    $insert = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    if ($insert) {
        return $insert_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope you will get the idea how simple to insert data into two tables using model.